# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: kendo-ui, syntax-error

In my project I want to display the popup while clear the kendo-grid by clicking "button" but I am getting  `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL  error occurred in browser debug`

Here is my  code:

```
function Filter() {
     $("#loading-msg").data("kendoWindow").center().open();
            $("form.k-filter-menu button[type='reset']").trigger("click");
    $("#loading-msg").data("kendoWindow").center().close();
}
```

Where I am wrong? Why I am getting this error?

[My fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/MG89G/394/)

Comment: There's no need to 'click' the reset button. Just call form.reset - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/form.reset

Comment: Not sure about the error - the code seems alright. Try commenting some of it.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply.The popup is raising but its closing and than data is filtering.but my requirement is popup mesaage has been shown up to data is filtering,and after that it has to be closed.my updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MG89G/394/   when i am checkin wit 10,000 records also it's happening same

Comment: when i am debugging this code in console i am getting this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of executing the close just after issuing the filter. My recommendation is closing the window on DataSource requestEnd event.

I.e.: Clear filter:

```
function clearFiter() {
    $("#loading-msg").data("kendoWindow").center().open();
    $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter([]);
}
```

and DataSource:

```
dataSource: {

    type: "odata",
    transport: {
        read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            fields: {
                OrderID: { type: "number" },
                Freight: { type: "number" },
                ShipName: { type: "string" },
                OrderDate: { type: "date" },
                ShipCity: { type: "string" }
            }
        }
    },
    pageSize: 10,
    serverPaging: true,
    serverFiltering: true,
    serverSorting: true,
    requestEnd : function () {
        $("#loading-msg").data("kendoWindow").close();
    }
},
```

Your code modified here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/MG89G/595/